# Collect all errors/exceptions occured, and output them

Tags: java, rest, jersey, bean-validation, jersey-2.0

I'm using Jersey to develop my REST Web Service.

I'm trying to implement validations, and for that I used the excellent integrations with JSR-303 Bean Validation Jersey offers.

I then define an ExceptionMapper to output what I want from the occurred errors. The problem is that sometimes, exceptions happen not in the context of the Bean Validation.

Example:

a client sends an invalid value for a float (e.g. "ABC"). Jackson throws an exception because it can't parse the given JSON to a float value. This is expected.

I could write an ExceptionMapper for this exception and output it to the client.
However, what I would want would be to ***gather all*** these different exceptions coming from various sources, and output them all. In other words, I would like to output the errors that happened during parsing and from Bean Validation in the same response, not individually.

*Is there any way to keep collecting all the exceptions and in the end output them all?*
The first problem I'm assuming will happen is that Bean Validation will never occur until Jackson parses the request correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you surmise, there is no way to do this because the exceptions happen at different times.  If the JSON is invalid then Jersey cannot proceed and so bean validation does not take place.

Comment: So there's no way to do this?
That is disappointing. :/

Client-side validation will have to handle this the way it's supposed to...

Comment: They're very different things.  Logically, if the JSON doesn't parse then how would you expect Jersey to proceed?

Comment: Makes sense, but the json itself **is** valid. It's just a normal string. The thing is that the given string isn't a valid float.
I was hoping I could just capture this exception, set the field to null, and proceed with bean validation and then output all the errors in one response.
Quite a challenge, I admit.